# File get content error

Tags: php

i got an error message when i try to do file_get_contents() function

> Warning: file_get_contents()
>   [function.file-get-contents]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server
>   configuration in
>   /data/20/1/112/111/1927437/user/2100551/htdocs/cti-dev/admin/my
>   path

My site is https ..

how this happend? Does any one help me ?

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurs when [allow_url_fopen](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html) is disabled. You'll need to use cURL to grab this file or change your PHP.ini config.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has disabled URL access in `fopen()` et alia, probably with [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).